# Is it possible to link values across multiple geometry nodes modifiers applied to the same object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an object with multiple geometry nodes modifiers, each one with a separate node tree. I would like to have some of the input values to be always the same in all of them, as if they were linked, so I don't have to manually update each one of them after I change some of these values.

**What I tried:**

- Controlling the values with an object info node with a controller object as input: it works but a separate controller object is needed for each one of my objects, and it would be too complex for what I'm trying to create.
- Controlling the values with attributes: the attributes are automatically updated across all the node trees but I need the valued to be simple floats, so they can be used for example as info for a grid node.

I know an easy solution for this would be to have a single geometry nodes modifier with all the separate nodetrees inside so they share the same inputs, in fact it's the setup I'm using right now, but having the nodetrees in separate modifiers would help me organize things better for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make an example. So if you are using setup something like this, there Fac value drives amount of green cubes:

[image]

And you want to have Fac value to be the same across modifiers:

[image]

In this case, you should use drivers. Click RMB on one value, and select "Copy as new Driver" from context menu. Then Click RMB on other values and select "Paste Driver". Now value from first value will be transferred to the second.

Comment: Hey sorry for being late to the party, but I'm very interested in knowing how you set up a node system where a Fac input controls the amount of green cubes vs. purple cubes.  In particular I'm trying to figure that out right now.  Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?